# Snowflake - REMOVE duplicated words/strings within a string in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i  have this code that works in oracle, to a certain degree

```
with data(str) as (
 select '3|BUTE PLACE|BUTE PLACE'  from dual union all
 select '3 BUTE PLACE BUTE PLACE'  from dual union all
 select '3 BUTE PLACE BUTE-PLACE'  from dual)

 select str, rtrim(str_new, ' ') new_str
   from data
  model
 partition by (rownum rn)
 dimension by (0 dim)
 measures(str, str||' ' str_new)
 rules
 iterate(10000) until (str_new[0] = previous(str_new[0]))
 (str_new[0]=regexp_replace(str_new[0],'(^| )([^ ]+ )(.*? )?\2+','\1\2\3'))
```

what i'm trying to figure out is how to use this code in snowflake where my address line is | separated and i want to be able to turn '3|BUTE PLACE|BUTE PLACE' into '3|BUTE PLACE'
for the purpose of address matching.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you are only looking to search for '|'. Perhaps put more explanation on what is needed, more sample data and expected output. From what you have mentioned you can just use split_part  select split_part(string,'|',1) || '|' || split_part(string,'|',2)

Comment: Hi, i want to be able to turn '3|BUTE PLACE|BUTE PLACE' into '3|BUTE PLACE', i want to be able to remove duplicated strings, if my sample has | then is 1 = 2 then nothing wrong, is 2=3 yes so remove one of them

Comment: You have 3 examples on the CTE, what's the expected result for each?

Comment: This "loop" you have could be butchered into a Recursive CTE, but that "data cleaning" would need to refined/improved, I spent some time doing this, but really how you fix/clean your data is so implementation specific, I got bored. Which is a hint this a a very poorly framed question.